# How to write and read exact double value?

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter, readlines

I want to write double value to file:`0\n0.1\n0.2\n0.3`, but in some value I can't write the exact `X.X` value, what was wrong:`5.999\n6.099\n6.199`, so how can I write and read the exact `X.X` value?

```
//stage 1: write value to file
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"data.txt"))
{
    for (double d = 0; d < 100; d += 0.1)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(d);
    }
}

//stage 2: read value from file and set to list
foreach (string s in File.ReadLines(@"data.txt"))
{
    list.Add(Convert.ToDouble(s));
}

//stage 3: compare value from list and iteration
int iMatchCount=1;
for (double d = 0; d < 100; d += 0.1)
{
    if (list.Contains(d))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match" + iMatchCount++ + ": " + d);
    }
}
Console.Read();
```

Comment: By not using a double.

Comment: `exact double value` is an oxymoron.  `double` is an approximate value.

Comment: The type `double` has a limit what can be stored. When you want to use/write exact number, then use `string` or `decimal`. But when you want to write the exact value stored in `double` number, that is a different thing. It not that hard *(at least not in C/C++)*, but this is probably not that what you want.,

Comment: I need float or double in my calculation,  I try decimals but it can't do `d += 0.1`

Comment: I had newer a problem with decimal: `d += 0.1M`

Comment: OK, try and successed, thanks to #Julo

Comment: Best is to use decimals, or if you can't/won't then use `.ToString("0.0")` to print the doubles according to your spec.

Comment: @ZoharPeled `double` is an exact value, only it is exact not for all the numbers you want :-) ... In the end, even in base 10, 1/3 can't be exactly represented.